# Python Pandas get index of value from one column to apply to another in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns and I have a word list. I want to filter one column of the dataframe by this list and save the matching rows of that column in a new list and at the same time get the value of the same index from the other column to save that value in a second list.

So I basically want to filter my dataframe by one column except that I have strings that I want to compare to words so I have to loop through them.

My code:

```
dataframe:
letter | sentence
----------------------------------------
L      | "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
C      | "consectetur adipiscing elit"
S      | "sed do eiusmod tempor"
I      | "incididunt ut labore et"
D      | "dolore magna aliqua."
```

```
word_list = ["elit","tempor", "aliqua"]
a = []
b = []

for d in dataframe.sentence:
    for word in word_list:
        if word in d:
            b.append(d)
            a.append(dataframe.letter[dataframe.sentence[d]])
            
            
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
```

My desired outcome:

```
new_df:
a   | b
-----------------------------------
C   | "consectetur adipiscing elit"
S   | "sed do eiusmod tempor"
D   | "dolore magna aliqua."
```

the problem is this line

`b.append(dataframe.letter[dataframe.sentence[d]])`

I don't know how to get the index from the one column that's currently looked at in the for loop and get the value of the same index of the other column.
The current error I get is this:

`KeyError: 'consectetur adipiscing elit'`

So I get the right value of the first iteration of the for loop but how do I get the index of that to apply to the other column?

Or is there maybe another way to filter the dataframe by my word list maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.apply()` with `any()`:

```
word_list = ["elit", "tempor", "aliqua"]

df = df[df["sentence"].apply(lambda x: any(w in x for w in word_list))]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  letter                     sentence
1      C  consectetur adipiscing elit
2      S        sed do eiusmod tempor
4      D         dolore magna aliqua.
```